# Printing Hello World Only 3 Times Not 5

Tags: c

I am trying to print hello world 5 times using a new function to do so *called*: **hello_world**. I am using a for loop in the **hello_world** function. This is the result I get:

```
C:\Users\darce\Desktop\c\functions\cmake-build-debug\functions.exe
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello_world(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        puts("Hello, World!");
        i++;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    hello_world(5);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is why is it only printing out 3 times instead of 5? For the param **int n** I made sure was 5 before I ran it.

Comment: That's because you're incrementing i at the end of the loop? The for loop already does that for you!

Comment: Just remove the `i++` from inside the loop.

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger

Comment: thanks for the comment @Fureeish will do, obviously I'm new so sorry for not knowing, lol. Might try to start debugging with **gdb**

Comment: That's fine, everybody started somewhere. Debugger will help you not only with solving bugs but also at improving your coding abilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you increment `i` twice. So, it will be 0, then 2, then 4, then 6, which is greater than 5.
In order to fix it, simply remove the `i++;` line after the `puts("Hello, World!");` or transform your `for` loop into a `while` loop.

#### Solution 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello_world(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        puts("Hello, World!");
    }
    /* CAN BE SIMPLIFIED BY REMOVING THE BRACES */

}

int main ()
{
    hello_world(5);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Solution 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello_world(int n) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        puts("Hello, World!");
        i++;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    hello_world(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: by common practice, if the loop has a definite and known end condition, you should stick with something terminal. In this case, the loop has a definite end, the given argument, so you should stick with `for`. `while` is used when you don't necessarily know the when it's going to end, such as asking for input until something correct is given.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are increamenting two times in the loop.
Remove the last i++ and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The form of this for loop is to always increment the counter variable after the final statement or function  has executed or returned, respectively.  So, any incrementation of 'i' in the loop body, in this case, will add 1 to the value of the for loop counter, corrupting the count.